# My dataset is unbalanced and has missing values, when does this become a problem?

Tags: dataset, missing-data, stata

I'm writing a thesis on data and variable specification sensitivity pertaining to economic growth. I have panel data with 39 countries ranging from 1981-2012, however, lots of countries had important variables missing for numerous years, I decided to drop some countries, but others still have some missing observations. The country Switzerland, for example, only has 6 years of data, whereas over half the sample has 23. What is the best way to approach this? Should I drop countries with low amount of periods? should I interpolate? Is this not an issue? I am planning on doing a fixed effects regression and a generalized methods of moments.

Also, how problematic are missing values for control variables?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! These seem like pretty standard issues in doing real panel data work. Consequently, the literature of your field should have many examples of how such issues are handled. What is discussed in the work you cite?

Comment: Some other works have used interpolation by averaging previous and next values, however, my dataset had so many observations missing, that this is not always possible. Many other works that I had cited did not touch on the subject, however, I saw one paper use a llc unit root test, which makes me believe that my data should be unbalanced.